# How to add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll?

Tags: c#, inputbox

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Favourite RPG?", "Game", "Cool!");
```

So what this does is basically ask the user their favourite RPG. Then it displays the default value. I know this is a small example but my program will not run because I'm getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Interaction' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Originally I found this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/191ddf61-3ae5-4845-b852-56bb9b77238a/input-message-box-in-c?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

The using statement you have is not a reference. It's merely a shortcut so you don't have to type the full namespace every time you want to access a member inside it.

Comment: How do you add reference? I never did this before.

Comment: Right click on your project file, go to `add reference` or `add` then `reference` depending on what version of VS you're using

Comment: Alright thanks :) I'll give this to you since you were the first. +1 to the rest who have helped :)

Answer (score 27):

In addition to `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` add the reference, too. Here's a visual answer:

[image]

Then

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Right click your `References` in the `Solution Explorer` click `Add Reference`,then search for `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and add it to your references.

For more information see this documentation:  [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)