# .Net Core Strings.Asc/Mid/Chr/Len missing even after importing Microsoft.VisualBasic

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core

I have to port some old VB code (cannot post for security reasons) over to a C# .Net Core application and I added the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to my using's but I still get errors saying  `Cannot resolve symbol Asc/Mid/Chr/Len`

Are these methods not available in `.net core`?

I have read that aside from using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` package there really isn't a replacement for these methods.

Do I have any options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Basic Runtime will be shipped with .NET core 3, so those functions will work then.

You can verify this by trying it in preview SDK: the following worked as expected for me (using Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.3.0 package on Nuget)

```
using static Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings;

class Program { 
   static void Main() { 
      Asc("Apple");
      Mid("Apple", 2, 3);
      Chr(100);
      Len("Apple");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the methods provided to you by the framework.

`Asc to Convert.ToInt32`

`Chr to Convert.ToChar`

`Len to String.Length`

`Mid to String.Substring`

Comment: Tried using those and they were not working as expected

Answer (score 2):

That stuff is all VB-specific, so not part of .NET Core. Don't use it in VB either. C# developers never use them anyway. Use the .NET equivalents, e.g. Convert.ToChar and String.Substring.

Comment: Tried using those and they were not working as expected

Comment: What "didn't work" about them? There's slight differences that you must account for, for example [`Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/mscorlib/system/convert.cs#L1118) is expecting the entire string to be a number, whereas `Asc(string)` [only looks at the first character](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/Microsoft.VisualBasic/runtime/msvbalib/Strings.vb#L243) ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... `Asc` also does some calculations for multi byte chars.. you probably really need `Convert.ToInt32(char)` or just `(int)("Apple"[0])`. Also, `Mid` is [1-based](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/Microsoft.VisualBasic/runtime/msvbalib/Strings.vb#L2004) whereas `Substring` is 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it now (15 June 2020) and the methods are available.
1) Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, version `10.4.0-preview.18571.3`. In 10.3.0 (the latest stable as of now) the methods are missing
2) Use netstandard2.0 or netstandard2.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the Microsoft.Visualbasic.dll, not just specifying the using.  See the following post:
[[How to add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212194/how-to-add-reference-to-microsoft-visualbasic-dll][1])

Comment: Shouldn't the dll get added automatically when installing the nuget package? I dont think I have ever had to manually add a dll after installing something from nuget

Comment: Try adding it manually anyway (takes about 5 seconds and can easily be undone) and see if it works afterwards - otherwise I am just wrong about the possible solution. It's been my experience that it might miss a dependency.